# Reuse parameters among multiple powershell functions

Tags: powershell

Consider two powershell functions:

```
function A {
params(
    [Parameter()]$x,
    [Parameter()]$y
)
Write-Host $x $y
}

function B {
params(
    [Parameter()]$x,
    [Parameter()]$z
)
Write-Host $x $z
}
```

I'd like to define a single parameter `$x` once (which could have fairly complex attributes that must be kept identical for both functions) and re-use it in both functions, so something like:

```
$x = {[Parameter()]$x}
function A {
params(
    $x,
    [Parameter()]$y
)
Write-Host $x $y
}

function B {
params(
    $x,
    [Parameter()]$z
)
Write-Host $x $z
}
```

(How) is this possible?

Comment: What's the context? You could possibly make a global, or script scope parameter depending on what the ultimate goal is.

Comment: Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26922153/14903754). Similar question, and one of the posts suggests using *Dynamic Parameters* to accomplish this, which makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To reuse parameter *declarations* across functions - as requested in your question - see the following section.
- To reuse parameter *values* (arguments) across functions, by way of *presets* (default value), see the bottom section.

---

In order to **reuse parameter declarations** - short of using design-time templating to *generate source code* - you need to to define a script block that creates a [*dynamic* parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#dynamic-parameters) that can be passed to the `dynamicparam` block of multiple advanced functions:

```sh
using namespace System.Management.Automation

# The script block that declares the dynamic parameter to be shared
# across functions.
$sharedDynParam = {
  
    # Define the -x parameter dynamically.
    $paramName = 'x'
    $dict = [RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
    $dict.Add(
      $paramName,
      [RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
        $paramName,
        [datetime],              # Type the parameter [datetime]. for instance.
        [ParameterAttribute] @{
          Mandatory = $true      # Make the parameter mandatory, for instance.
          # ParameterSetName = 'default' # Assign it to a parameter set, if neeeded.
        }
      )
    )

    # Return the dictionary
    return $dict
}

function A {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    $y
  )
  
  # Assign the shared dynamic parameter.
  dynamicparam { & $sharedDynParam } 

  # The use of `dynamicparam { ... }` requires use of an explicit
  # `process { ... }` block (and optionally `begin { ... }` and
  # `end { ... }`, as needed).
  process {
    # Note: A dynamic -x parameter cannot be accessed as $x
    #       Instead, it must be accessed via the $PSBoundParameters dictionary.
    "[$($PSBoundParameters['x'])] - [$y]"
  }

}

function B {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    $z
  )

  # Assign the shared dynamic parameter.
  dynamicparam { & $sharedDynParam } 

  process {
    "[$($PSBoundParameters['x'])] - [$z]"
  }

}


# Sample calls, 
A -x '1970-01-01' -y yval
B -x '1970-01-02' -z zval
```

Output:

```sh
[01/01/1970 00:00:00] - [yval]
[01/02/1970 00:00:00] - [zval]
```

---

To **preset the value of a parameter** by a given name across commands, use the [`$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues):

```sh
# Preset a parameter value for all commands ('*') that have
# an -x ('x') parameter.
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ '*:x' = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = 2 } }

function A {  
  [CmdletBinding()] # This makes the function an *advanced* one, which respects 
                    # $PSDefaultParameterValues; similarly, at least one
                    # parameter-individual [Parameter()] attribute does the same.
  param(
    $x,
    $y
  )
  "[$x] - [$y]"
}
  
function B {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    $x,
    $z
  )
  "[$x] - [$z]"
}

# Sample calls, without an -x argument, relying on
# $PSDefaultParameterValues to provide it automatically.
A -y yval
B -z zval
```

Output, showing that parameter `-x` was automatically bound via `$PSDefaultParameterValues`:

```sh
[@{foo=1; bar=2}] - [yval]
[@{foo=1; bar=2}] - [zval]
```

Comment: I see, @alazyworkaholic - please see my update.